# How to watch inactive record rules in OpenERP (Odoo)?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

How to watch inactive record rules in OpenERP (Odoo)?

If I create a new record rule and mark it as active, it is displayed but when I mark it as inactive, it is getting disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Odoo, you need to go Settings => Technical => Security => Record Rules => now go to search filter and give Active = False and than click on Apply

[image: odoo_inactive_record_rule]

In OpenERP v7, you need to go Settings => Technical => Security => Record Rules => now go to search filter and give Active = False and than click on Apply:

[image: openerp_inactive_record_rule]

Comment: Thanks Odedra...Its too simple than expected. I was just trying to enter the requried record into the search field. But this helps.

Comment: According to question I wrote answer. If you need something else than you need to describe more or you may accept that answer and ask a new question. Thanks